# How to write window event log by order

Tags: c#, event-log

I'm trying to write some message to windows event log:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    for(int i=0; i< 10; i++)
    {
        WriteSystemEventLog(i.ToString());
    }
    Console.ReadKey();
}

public static void WriteSystemEventLog(string msg, EventLogEntryType type = EventLogEntryType.Error)
{
    EventLog myLog = null;
    try
    {
        myLog = new EventLog();
        myLog.Source = "My application";
        myLog.WriteEntry(msg, type);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error occured during write system event log, error message: " + e.Message);
    }
    if (myLog != null)
    {
        myLog.Dispose();
        myLog = null;
    }
}
```

Open event log, sort by date, expected:
0 1 2 3 ...

Actual:
2 3 1 9 0 ...

Add 1 second sleep could solve this problem, but is there any other way?

Comment: what is the timestamp you are seeing for those logs in the event logger?

Comment: The timestamps are identical. The logs are generated in one second.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sadly, events in system event log are only ordered to a resolution of one second, because they use UNIX timestamp - number of whole seconds since the start of 1970. This appears to be a system limitation you can't do much about.